# Connecting “C” (common) wire for Nest thermostats

Tags: thermostat-c-wire, nest, zoned-heating

I am planning to get two Nest Thermostats for my 2 zone HVAC system.  It looks like blue C wire is already there for both thermostats, but not connected (existing thermostats run on batteries).  I think I need to connect C wire to each Nest thermostat and to C on Thermostat Zone 1 and Thermostat Zone 2 at the zone control unit (see pic).

Is that going to be sufficient to power Nest thermostats or do I have to connect C wire running from the zone control unit to the gas furnace?  If so, I don’t see C slot at the zone control unit (see pic), where do I connect common wire running from the furnace to the zone control unit?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What make/model is your zone board? Can you post a wiring diagram for it, for that matter?

Comment: It’s Honeywell EMM-3 https://www.alpinehomeair.com/product/zone-control-systems/forced-air-zone-controls/forced-air-zone-control-panels/honeywell/emm-3

Comment: I added wiring diagram to my original post, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

### Your thermostat C terminal is right there in front of you, between G and the motor terminals

Your zone board indeed provides C terminals on the zone terminal blocks.  They're between the G terminal and the motor connections for that zone, so you can just unwind those blue wires and connect them to the respective C terminals.

### The zone board doesn't need C from the furnace though

However, since your zone board has its own 24VAC transformer powering it, it doesn't need a C wire from the furnace.  So, you don't need to hook up the C wire from the furnace to anything.

Comment: Right, I know C wires need to be connected to zone terminals for each thermostat.  What I’m not sure about is C wire running from the zone control unit to the furnace.  There is a set of wires along with a spare C wire on the left (cut off from the pic) which run to the furnace.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the pic/schematic, you don't need to worry about the C wire coming from the furnace. That zone controller appears to have it's own transformer connected on the right (on schematic, not shown in pic though) powering it. Confirm it's a 40VA transformer since we can't see it.

Taking a quick look at the specs of that board shows it draws ~10.75VA, so that leaves more than enough power for 2 Nest stats.

Comment: Yes, I can see two transformer wires on the right connected to the zone control unit, thanks!